# How to get an input while continuously drawing graphics?

Tags: java, draw

I'm a total noob who is making a turn based game.
I want it to draw graphic all the time and take inputs when needed.

```
    while(isPlaying){
        do{
          shoot(); //input and action
          moveBalls();  //after shoot is finished   
          showScore();
        } while ((!miss)&&(!foul));
        switchTurn();

        draw();         
        c.sleep(10);
    }
```

I know this will make the game to not draw until all the actions are finished.
I want it to draw every 10 ticks so that the graphics can be changed while in action and while waiting for an input.
I don't know where to put draw() and c.sleep(10).

It would be nice if someone can give a little help.

Comment: The answer will depend on the framework you're using. For Swing, you'd use the Key Bindings API

Comment: it's not clear without the real code but usually, the drawing part is done in the same loop than the logic part and the input reading part.

Comment: In a main game loop: input, logic, rendering, (sleeping). If someone is typing something in then you can process that input over several frames.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine, but if it were in a JApplet you should do this:

```
while(isPlaying){
    do{
      shoot(); 
      moveBalls();      
      showScore();
    } while ((!miss)&&(!foul));
    switchTurn();

    repaint();         
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Oh, and you should get input through JTextField.